# C# Restful Web service returning int value

Tags: c#, rest

This is my first semester taking C# and working on web services. I started the semester off learning SOAP, now I am learning REST. I hear REST is the more popular one to use. So far it seems harder to user to me, but I am still very new to it.

So I am trying to create restful service. Actually creating the service is working. I want to get a return int value from the service and on my client/console side store that int value into a int arrayList.

Problem is the rest service is returning the entire xml string. like this

```
<int xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/">0</int>
```

I just want the 0, so I can store that value in my arrayList. I feel like C# should have some simple library or something that allows me to just get the values in between the xml tags.

I wrote up test code to get me a better idea of how to get data from my REST services.

Here is code in the service contract of WCF (we are supposed to use WCF in this assignment, so I am using it in my test code).

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IService1
{
    [OperationContract]
    [WebGet(BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare)]
    int getTrafficAccidentsByZip(int zCode);

    [OperationContract]
    [WebGet(UriTemplate = "latlonValues?lonVal={lonVal}&latVal={latVal}", 
            BodyStyle =WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare)]
    int getTrafficAccidentByLonLat(double lonVal, double latVal);

    // TODO: Add your service operations here
}
```

Here is the implementation of the contracts. Like I said, this is test code. So I am just returning 0

```
public class Service1 : IService1
{
    public int getTrafficAccidentsByZip(int zCode)
    {
         return 0;
    }

    public int getTrafficAccidentByLonLat(double lonVal, double latValue)
    {
         return 0;
    }
}
```

This is what I have in main. You can see below that I tried to convert the string to int. That caused an error.

```
string url = @"http://localhost:14722/Service1.svc/getTrafficAccidentsByZip";

HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();
Stream responseStream = response.GetResponseStream();

StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(responseStream);
// int test = Convert.ToInt32( reader);
String json = reader.ReadToEnd();
// int test = Convert.ToInt32(json);
Console.WriteLine(json);
```

I feel like this should be really easy. BUT I have been having a hard time finding simple examples of how to do this online.

Any good online C# REST examples or youtube videos would be greatly appreciated. WIth examples. I learn from examples.

Answer (score 0):

The rest call returns the XML of your call, rendered as text. The two most popular forms of rest are Json and XML and will / can parse differently depending on the headers you use etc.  Your result will either look like that or something like:

```
{"result" : "0" }
```

Either way it's coming back as a string and not a binary 0 with rest.